# Angular 2 SafeValue must use [property]=binding with input

Tags: javascript, angular, pipes-filters

I want to replace certain words with input fields, I have created method, that must replace and Pipe for safe insert of input field, but it doesn't work...What am I doing wrong? Please help!
Here is my code

part2.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../sample02-simpleService/data.service';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'part2',
  template: `
    <p>{{itemsSource | sanitizeHtml}}</p>    
  `,
  providers: [DataService]

})
export class Part2Component implements OnInit {
  public itemsSource: string;
  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.abc = this.dataService.getData3();
    this.itemsSource = this.dataService.getData2();
    this.abc.forEach(str => {
      let regExp = new RegExp(str.toString(), 'g');
      this.itemsSource = this.itemsSource.replace(regExp, '<input/>');
    });
  }
}
```

I Take data from DataService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
          @Injectable()
export class DataService {
            getData2() {
              let items3: string = 'Das ist unsere Erde. Die Erde ist ein Planet. ' +
              'Sie ist der einzige Planet auf dem wir leben können. ' +
              'Auf keinem anderen Planet gibt es Menschen oder Tieren.Es gibt acht Planeten. ' +
              'Dass ist meine Lieblings.';
              return items3;
            }
            getData3(){
              let items4: string[] = ['Planeten', 'Planeten', 'eine', 'Tiere', 'viele', 'Planet', 'keine', 'meine'];
              return items4;
            }
          }
```

And I have custom Pipe here

```
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
import {DomSanitizer, SafeHtml} from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Pipe({
  name: 'sanitizeHtml'
})
export class SanitizeHtml implements PipeTransform  {

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(v: string): SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
  }
}
```

I guess, I am very close to right answer, please, help me...